# How to get a get a model not in my collection, but in my online database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I've built a simple CRUD app with Backbone and Express on the backend. When I load up the app I call app.collection.fetch() and run a find() query in mongoose. I limit this query so I don't get the whole collection. (I didn't think it would be smart to fetch a whole database).

When I go to a URL in my page it looks like this:

```
coolapp.com/#posts/slug-of-post
```

In order to populate this "show" page I need to get the model with the slug in the hash. However, I can't search my collection for the model because my Backbone collection is not an exact match from my mongo database. I need to search my database on the server, not my local collection. Is there a way to do this with backbone natively, or should I just write my own function using ajax?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood your collection holds something like the metadata about models in your backend, When you go to a specific route, you want to fetch the full data for that particular model.

Well, there is a built in way to do this in backbone:

Define a model with a `urlRoot` like  like `posts/`.

There is no rule that a model must have a collection. When your application navigates to the specific route, create an instance of this model with the respective `id`, and do a `model.fetch()`. This will trigger a request like `posts/123` for fetching particular model's data which you can pass to your view.

Define such a route in your backend that responds with respective data and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no inbuilt function to do that. One suggestion for code modularity and ease of usage :
You can bind a new function say "searchPost" to the collection and implement all your logic to perform local search and online search in it. It will end up looking like : `collection.searchPost(slug)`